# SharePoint custom form how to search in dropdown inputs with full text?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I'm not entirely sure if that's even possible. I have Dropdown inputs with search function enabled.

`SearchFields = ["Value"]` and `IsSearchable = true`

For example I have value `Will Smith` for search this value need to type `Will`, but if I type `Smith` as a first value is not searched.

Any ideas how to setup to full text?

Comment: What is the current formula in `items` property of your combo box control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `items` property of your combo box control like this:

```
Filter(Choices('SharePointListName'.ColumnName),Self.SearchText in Value)
```

OR

```
Filter(Choices('SharePointListName'.ColumnName),ComboBox1.SearchText in Value)
```

Where `ComboBox1` is the name of your combo box control in power apps.